# Is it possible to combine uniform initialization and constructors?

Tags: c++

I know I can do this by using an array to store the data for Matrix.

```
Matrix<2, 2> m = { 1, 2
                   3, 4 };
```

But I would like to do this and use a vector instead, as using the array is pretty bad when matrices become big and you run out of stack space

```
Matrix m(2, 2) = { 1, 2
                   3, 4 };
```

Can this (or something similar) be done?

Comment: Sure, you can write a constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Are you sure? AFAICT this is not possible ([live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t$309))

Comment: Are you hell-bent on that syntax or would a slightly different invocation be okay?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the template arguments to initialise a vector? To be honest, I'd just use an `std::array`. If the client has an issue with the stack, they can dynamically allocate your `Matrix`.

Comment: I'm confused.  What about the `Matrix<2,2> m` example prevents it from storing data in the free store (or a `vector`)?  Do you need the size to be dynamic and not determined at compile time?

Comment: Extending delnans question: Does "something similar" include `Matrix m(2, 2, {1,2,3,4});`?

Comment: @Yakk I was unable to have the same syntax (VS2012 RTM) using a vector even if the size were determined at compile time

Comment: @ DyP that syntax would be acceptable. Anything that gets me away from m(0, 0) = 1; m(1, 0) = 2; .... would be great

Comment: @aCuria `template<size_t a, size_t b> struct Matrix { std::vector<int> d; Matrix( std::initializer_list<int> l ):d(a*b) { d.assign(l); }` does a two-pass construct, but should work.  Your library might not support `vector::assign( initializer_list<T> )`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fixed size at compile time, but would like to use dynamic allocation, you could either chose the allocation type ("stack" / "heap") of each object individually or build the dynamic allocation into the `Matrix` class.

An example of dynamic allocation outside the `Matrix` class. Note the use of initializer-lists prevents from checking at compile-time the number of elements passed to the ctor at (other than by declaring `contexpr` instances of `Matrix`). Therefore, I've introduced a rather silly addition to demonstrate compile-time size checks.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template < typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns >
struct Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<T> p)
    {
       if(p.size() != rows*columns) { /* throw */ }

       std::copy( p.begin(), p.end(), storage_member.begin() );
    }
    Matrix(std::array<T, columns*rows> const& p)
    {
       std::copy( p.begin(), p.end(), storage_member.begin() );
    }

    Matrix(std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list<T> > p)
    {
       if(p.size() != rows) { /* throw */ }

       auto itRow = p.begin();
       for(std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row, ++itRow)
       {
          if(itRow->size() != columns) { /* throw */ }

          auto itCol = itRow->begin();
          for(std::size_t col = 0; col < columns; ++col, ++itCol)
          {
             storage_member[col+row*columns] = *itCol;
          }
       }
    }
    Matrix(std::array<std::array<T, columns>, rows> const& p)
    {
       for(std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
       {
          for(std::size_t col = 0; col < columns; ++col)
          {
             storage_member[col+row*columns] = p[row][col];
          }
       }
    }

    // getters, setters
    T& operator() (std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
    {
        return storage_member[col+row*columns];
    }
private:
    // storage, e.g.
    std::array<T, columns*rows> storage_member;
};

template < typename T, typename... TP>
constexpr std::array<T,sizeof...(TP)+1> m(T&& p, TP... pp)
{
   return {{p, pp...}};
}

// usage:
int main()
{
   using My_Matrix_Type = Matrix < int, 2, 2 >;

   std::unique_ptr < My_Matrix_Type > pmyMatrix0{ new My_Matrix_Type( {1,2,3,4} ) };
   std::unique_ptr < My_Matrix_Type > pmyMatrix1{ new My_Matrix_Type( {{1,2},{3,4}} ) };

   // with compile-time size checks
   std::unique_ptr < My_Matrix_Type > pmyMatrix2{ new My_Matrix_Type( m(1,2,3,4) ) };
   std::unique_ptr < My_Matrix_Type > pmyMatrix3{ new My_Matrix_Type( m(m(1,2), m(3,4)) ) };
   // a more fancy but possible syntax, would require some additional effort:
   //std::unique_ptr < My_Matrix_Type > pmyMatrix4{ new My_Matrix_Type( b(1,2)(3,4) ) };


   std::cout << (*pmyMatrix0)(1,1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << (*pmyMatrix1)(1,1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << (*pmyMatrix2)(1,1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << (*pmyMatrix3)(1,1) << std::endl;
}
```

In the example above, you can immediately replace `storage_member` by a dynamically allocated array to make the dynamic allocation built-in.

---

If you don't know the size at compile-time, you had to build the dynamic allocation into the `Matrix` class (as mentioned above). As you can deduce the size (columns, rows) of 2-level initializer-lists, you only had to remove the ctors taking fixed-size arrays and change the ctor taking 1-level initializer-lists, like:

```
template < typename T > // no size parameters!
struct Matrix
{
    Matrix(std::size_t columns, std::size_t rows, std::initializer_list<T> p);
    Matrix(std::initializer_list< std::initializer_list<T> > p);
    // maybe an additional ctor for dynamically allocated arrays

    // getters, setters, data members
};

// usage:
Matrix myMatrix0( 2, 2, {1,2,3,4} );
Matrix myMatrix1( {{1,2},{3,4}} );
```

Comment: If anyone knows how to make this work with `make_unique` (especially the examples with initializer-lists), I'd appreciate a comment/edit.